# Include raw XML when deserializing XML

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have the following XML and classes that are being serialized from it:

```
<Alerts>
  <io id="1">
    <name>Foo</name>
    <status>Active</status>
  </io>
  <io id="2">
    <name>Bar</name>
    <status>Inactive</status>
  </io>
</Alerts>

[XmlRoot("Alerts")]
[Serializable]
public class Alerts
{
    [XmlElement("io")]
    public List<Alert> { get; set; }
}

public class Alert
{
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

What I require is a property in my `Alert` class, that upon deserialization contains the XML of its node. For example, after deserializing the provided XML, I end up with a list of 2 `Alert` objects. I would need the first alert to have a property that contains this as a string:

```
<io id="1">
    <name>Foo</name>
    <status>Active</status>
</io>
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need a string property in your Alert class to store the xml representation of another alert? Could you have a property of type Alert or even a property of type IEnumerable<Alert>?

Comment: I need a string property in my Alert class to store the XML representation of its _own_ alert, if that makes sense.

Comment: Is it important to you that the literal string be stored, or could you generate it on the getter of a property for instance?

Comment: No it's not really important, either strategy would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to actually accomplish this is to have a string property, and then in your xml replace the xml reserved characters with entity character references so it doesn't get serialized as xml. So your xml would look something like:

```
<io id="1">
    <name>Foo</name>
    <status>Active</status>
    <innerAlert>
        &lt;io id=&quot;3&quot;&gt;&lt;name&gt;FooBar&lt;/name&gt;&lt;status&gt;Inactive&lt;/status&gt;&lt;innerAlert&gt;&lt;/innerAlert&gt;&lt;/io&gt;
    </innerAlert>
```

I still keep going back to my comment and thinking that you might be better off adding a property of type Alert or IEnumerable to your Alert class and let the tree deserialize out all the way down, but maybe that's just not an option to you.